# Can I downgrade xdebug in ddev?

Tags: ddev

There's a conflict between SublimeText and xdebug 2.6.0, when using SublimeText's xdebug package and PHP 7, resulting in no context information being displayed during debugging (the sent data is badly formed, according to the console). Downgrading to xdebug 2.5.5 circumvents the issue in other local environments I use.

Is it possible to (easily?) downgrade xdebug to 2.5.5 in the ddev environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the v0.20.0 release sudo is available in the web container, so you can use a post-start hook or `ddev ssh` or `ddev exec` to make any changes to containers that you need. You'll have to figure out how to do that downgrade on Debian 8 though.

Comment: Awesome. Would the changes made in the character "stick" between ddev restarts, or should I look into using post-start hooks?

Comment: You'll need post-start hooks. v0.20.0 is out. I'll edit to show that. It would be great if you could do a followup with your actual solution.

Comment: I've had trouble getting the downgrade to work. But that's in large part due to my inexperience with the xdebug compilation/configuration process.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll end up happy with this, but I was able to download the old deb package from https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/php-xdebug/download: `ddev ssh; cd /tmp/;  wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xdebug/php-xdebug_2.5.0-1_amd64.deb; dpkg -i php-xdebug_*; enable_xdebug - it seems awkward but would at least let you try it out.  You'd really like PHPStorm though...

Comment: Ran through that and xdebug stopped loading according to phpinfo(). Thanks for your help with this, I do appreciate it—hate to waste any more of your time for a problem that should be fixed in Sublime and that I can circumvent via VS Code (which I confirmed works fine) or PHPStorm (which I assume works fine).

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody will stil have to use Xdebug 2 those days, you can add this file .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile whith that content

```
RUN npm install --global forever
RUN echo "Built from $BASE_IMAGE" > /tmp/built-from.txt

# Modification to use an old xdebug version
RUN sudo apt-get update  \
    && sudo apt-get install php-pear php7.3-dev -y  \
    && sudo apt-get install libcurl3-openssl-dev  \
    && sudo pecl install pecl_http  \
    && sudo pecl install xdebug-2.9.8 

# Adds "zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so" to php.ini
RUN echo "zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini
```

It works for me with with
ddev version v1.19.3 and drud/ddev-webserver:v1.19.3-1.

Just don't forget to ddev restart for changes to be applied